# Sort dictionary with tuple values and filter top k elements

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I'd like to sort a dictionary based on the second value of the tuple and get the top k elements.
The code below works when there is one value per key. How do I change it with tuples or lists or numpy arrays?

```
A = {'a':(3, 4), 'b':(1, 2), 'c': (10,11)}
newA = dict(sorted(A.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:k])
```

desired output:

```
'b'
'a'
'c'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget that dicts are not stable - their ordering can and will change, resulting in disastrous bugs if you least expect it, because this happens most on key insertion. So use an OrderedDict from collections

```
In [1]: from collections import OrderedDict
In [2]: OrderedDict(sorted(A.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=False)[:k])
Out[2]: OrderedDict([('b', (1, 2)), ('a', (3, 4)), ('c', (10, 11))])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newA = dict(sorted(A.iteritems(), key=lambda i: i[1][1], reverse=True)[:k])
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
In [1]: A = {'a':(3, 4), 'b':(1, 2), 'c': (10,11)}

In [2]: B = A.items()

In [3]: B.sort(key=lambda x:x[1][1])

In [4]: B
Out[4]: [('b', (1, 2)), ('a', (3, 4)), ('c', (10, 11))]

In [5]: print "\n".join([x[0] for x in B]) #expected output
b
a
c
```

Comment: Is this the same as @Amber s answer?

Comment: How does the timing scale with increased keys or values with more items?

Comment: @wwii, Amber's answer gives you a dict. it does not seems good to me to use dict if the order is important.

Comment: regarding timings, thanks for pointing out. I think that was not suitable in this case. So, removed it